# Counting unique values against a subset of a list

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, countif, conditional-statements

I'm trying to count how many unique supervisors a particulate employee has. (See an example data set below.)

I'm able to do this in a round about way, but I'm wondering if any of you experts out there might be able to figure out a one-step formula to do the same job.

My round about method is:

1. Concatenate the staff member and supervisor into single string: `=CONCATENATE(A2,"-",B2)`
2. Use an `if` statement with `countif` to give 1 for first instance of the staff-supervisor string and zero for any occurrence after: `=IF(COUNTIF($D$2:$D2,D2)>1,0,1)`
3. Use `sumif` to add sum this column but for only that particular staff member: `=SUMIF($A$2:$A$13,A2,$E$2:$E$13)`

As you can see, the **Sum if** column arrives at the correct value, as is manually entered the **Number of unique supervisors** column.

```
Data                 "Goal"                         Calculated
------------------   ----------------------------   --------------------------------------
Staff | Supervisor | Number of unique supervisors | Concat | 1 if first instance | Sum if 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Anne  | F          | 1                            | Anne-F | 1                   | 1      
Bob   | A          | 2                            | Bob-A  | 1                   | 2      
Bob   | B          | 2                            | Bob-B  | 1                   | 2      
Mary  | D          | 2                            | Mary-D | 1                   | 2      
Mary  | D          | 2                            | Mary-D | 0                   | 2      
Mary  | E          | 2                            | Mary-E | 1                   | 2      
Sue   | G          | 2                            | Sue-G  | 1                   | 2      
Sue   | H          | 2                            | Sue-H  | 1                   | 2      
Tom   | I          | 2                            | Tom-I  | 1                   | 2      
Tom   | I          | 2                            | Tom-I  | 0                   | 2      
Tom   | J          | 2                            | Tom-J  | 1                   | 2      
Tom   | J          | 2                            | Tom-J  | 0                   | 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `C2`, formula copied down :

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A$2:A$13=A2)/COUNTIFS(A$2:A$13,A$2:A$13,B$2:B$13,B$2:B$13))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have Office 365 with the `FILTER` and `UNIQUE` functions, you can use:

```
=COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER($B$2:$B$13,A2=$A$2:$A$13)))
```

Comment: This could also be the accepted answer, but alas, I can only pick one.

Answer (score 0):

*You need few array (CSE) formula, to produce summary kind of output, and it fixes the issue also:*

[image]

**How it works:**

- An array (CSE) Formula in cell `H161`:

  ```
  {=IFERROR(INDEX($F$161:$F$172, MATCH(0,COUNTIF($H$160:H160, $F$161:$F$172), 0)),"")}
  ```
- Enter this array (CSE) formula in cell `I161`:

  ```
  {=IF(SUMPRODUCT((($F$161:$F$172=H161))/COUNTIFS($F$161:$F$172,$F$161:$F$172&"",$G$161:$G$172,$G$161:$G$172&""))=0,"",SUMPRODUCT((($F$161:$F$172=H161))/COUNTIFS($F$161:$F$172,$F$161:$F$172&"",$G$161:$G$172,$G$161:$G$172&"")))}
  ```

**N.B.**

- Finish formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** & fill down.
- Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.